# ui.bootstrap deforms the <progress> HTML tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, progress

In my HTML file I have a `<progress>` tag and I also injected the `ui.bootstrap` dependency to my controller as follows:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",["ui.bootstrap"]);
```

In this configuration, AngularJS converts the `<progress></progress>` into:

```
<div class="progress ng-isolate-scope" ng-transclude=""></div>
```

When I remove "ui.bootstrap" it works fine. You can play out with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yaprak/6fM5S/1/) sample JSFiddle.

When `progress` turned into `<div class="progress ng-isolate-scope" ng-transclude=""></div>`
it disappears. I understand that there is a directive called `progress` in ui.bootstrap that makes this conversion.

So, how can I make this progress bar work? Or, how can I disable the `progress` directive of angular-ui without removing the dependency?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this same issue. A simple workaround is to use ng-non-bindable which is a standard angualr directive. The drawback is you can't use any angular directives or bindings within the progress element.

```
<progress ng-non-bindable></progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question or which version of `uiBootstrap` you are using.

The directive should be:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <progressbar value="55"></progressbar>
</div>
```

I changed the version of `uiBootstrap` and included the necessary `bootstrap.min.css` in this forked [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hj8jS/) and everything seems to work fine. (look at external resources)

Comment: Uhh, now I understand. You have a native html progress tag on your page and this is overwritten/destroyed by the ui progressbar directive which consists of the the custom directives progressbar, progress and bar. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/progressbar/progressbar.js I would account this as a bug in ui-bootstrap. Custom directives should have another name than native tags. I'm afraid that this can only be fixed by changing the ui source and the according templates. Please ignore my stoopid answer.