# can I bind an attribute on an element with ng-non-bindable?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, progress

I am trying to get an html5 progress bar working in Angular.

Similarly to [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882382/ui-bootstrap-deforms-the-progress-html-tag) I have an old version of `ui.bootstrap` on the page which has it's own `progress` directive causing my `<progress></progress>` to be converted into `<div class="progress ng-isolate-scope" ng-transclude=""></div>`

I can fix this problem by using ng-non-bindable
`<progress ng-non-bindable></progress>`

However now that this progress element is non-bindable, I can't figure out how to dynamically set the value from my controller.  Ideally I would like to do something like this:

`<progress ng-non-bindable ng-bind-value="ctrl.currentProgress"=></progress>`

Is there anyway I can use `ng-non-bindable` on the element, but somehow bind the value attribute so I can dynamically set it?

[ng-bind-attr](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1925) looked promising but I wasn't able to get it working/find documentation

I am using Angular 1.5.8 and ideally I wouldn't update bootstrap at this point (to remove the 'progress' name clash) unless I have to.